# How to get values of associated table column using group by clause in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 3 tables namely items, fields and field_values as shown below. I am grouping records based on two fields items.name and fields.name. I want sql query to return items.name, sum(items.qty) and array of field_values.value(associated with the grouped records).

### Table items

| id | name | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | noodles | 1 |
| 2 | biscuits | 1 |
| 3 | papers | 1 |

### Table fields

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | branch code |
| 2 | branch manager name |

### Table field_values

| id | value | item_id | field_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | office branch 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | office branch 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | office branch 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | office branch 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | office branch 5 | 3 | 1 |

**Expected:** As per data in table field_values

> item noodles with total quantity 3 is linked with office branch 1, office branch 3, office branch 4
>
> > item biscuits with quantity 1 linked with office branch 2
> >
> > > item papers with quantity 1 is linked with office branch 5

**Expected Result**

| name | quantity | delivery_to_branches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| noodles | 3 | {"office branch 1","office branch 3","office branch 4"} |
| biscuits | 1 | {"office branch 2"} |
| papers | 1 | {"office branch 5"} |

I am running following sql query:

```
SELECT
    items.name,
    sum(qty) AS quantity,
    array(
        SELECT field_values.value
            FROM field_values
        WHERE field_values.item_id IN (
            SELECT ID FROM items
        )
        AND fields.name = 'branch code'
    ) AS "delivery_to_branches"
FROM
  items
INNER JOIN field_values ON field_values.item_id = items.id
INNER JOIN fields ON field_values.field_id = fields.id
GROUP BY
    items.name, fields.name
```

**Got unexpected result for field delivery_to_branches**

When i execute above Sql query, I am getting correct values for name and quantity but array values showing incorrect for delivery_to_branches. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!!

| name | quantity | delivery_to_branches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| noodles | 3 | {"office branch 1", "office branch 2","office branch 3","office branch 4", "office branch 5"} |
| biscuits | 1 | {"office branch 1", "office branch 2","office branch 3","office branch 4", "office branch 5"} |
| papers | 1 | {"office branch 1", "office branch 2","office branch 3","office branch 4", "office branch 5"} |

Comment: Please refrain from [adding images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and use proper *consumable text* for sample data.

Comment: Your subquery returns all the items since you have `field_values.item_id IN (SELECT ID from items)`.

But I think you can just replace the `array(...)` with `array_agg(field_values.value)`.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for alert, just edited my post with consumable text for sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `array_agg()` in the outer query with a filter:

```
SELECT i.name,
       SUM(qty) AS quantity,
       ARRAY_AGG(fv.value) FILTER (WHERE f.name = 'branch code') as delivery_to_branches
FROM items i JOIN
     field_values fv
     ON fv.item_id = i.id JOIN
     fields f
     ON fv.field_id = f.id
```

GROUP BY i.name;